# a problem with showing PDF in window in IE

Tags: angular, pdf, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem with PDF showing in front of the properties panel in IE but not in Chrome.

[in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95k9r.png)

[in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qc9y.png)

tried using z-index but had no success

using angular 7.13

I know IE support has stopped and no one likes it but it will take time for the company to stop using it.

edit:
added some of the code, I can't add more because of company protocols.
I don't think it's a codding problem, it works on all other browsers.

````
```html for the file viewer
<div *ngSwitchCase="actionsBarType == eActionsBar.Viewer ? eActionsBar.Viewer : actionsBarType == 
eActionsBar.ViewerFullScreen ? eActionsBar.ViewerFullScreen :
                            actionsBarType == 
eActionsBar.ArchivesViewer ? eActionsBar.ArchivesViewer :
                        actionsBarType == eActionsBar.ArchivesViewerFullScreen ? eActionsBar.ArchivesViewerFullScreen : '' ">
  <mat-expansion-panel #panel [hideToggle]="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header style="max-height: 38px !important;">
      <mat-panel-title>
        <div *ngTemplateOutlet="actions"></div>
      </mat-panel-title>

    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div *ngIf="item != null">
      <viewer-properties [viewerData]="item [viewerPropertiesTemplate] = "viewerPropertiesTemplate">
      </viewer-properties>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</div>
````

````
```html for the properties panel
        <div [ngSwitch]="viewerPropertiesTemplate">
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'properties'">
                <div *ngIf="viewerData.ecmContentType == eECM_ContentType.FILE" class="viewer-properties rtl">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="title">שם קובץ: </span>
                        <span class="text">{{viewerData.name | removeSuffix }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="title">מזהה קובץ: </span>
                        <span class="text">{{viewerData.id}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="title">זמן העלאת הקובץ למאגר: </span>
                        <span class="text">{{viewerData.creationDate | date : "d/M/yy HH:mm"}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="title">הקובץ נוצר ע"י: </span>
                        <span class="text">{{viewerData.creatorName.value}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="title">סוג קובץ: </span>
                        <span class="text">{{viewerData.fileTypeStr }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <actions-bar [item]="viewerData" [actionsBarType]="eActionsBar.ViewerProperties"></actions-bar>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
````

````
```css 
.viewer-properties{
position: relative;
height: auto;
z-index: 1000;
padding: 1%;
pointer-events: all;
cursor: auto;
/*cursor: pointer;*/
}
```
`
````

Comment: If possible, could you provide complete code example so we can reproduce this issue? I think this will help solve the problem. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

solved it, by using angular material Platform cdk to differentiate Trident based browsers, and downloading files while in IE instead of opening them in the page.